# prevent asynctask to run after intent and starting the activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have tried to prevent an asynctask to run after changing the activity through intent but even after calling finnish() the activity is still creating.

I am trying to see if a user got filled the username/password or not in my application, if they are not filled it should be redirected to the loggin activity to complete them.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(musicPlayer.this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
```

If the fields are completed the intent won't occur and the asynctask will do the log-in.

```
        new asynctaskMethod().execute();
```

I am not interested about other method to do the log-in because I am doing it through an api of a cloud, I don't have a `SESSION` to work with.

Every search I've done gave me the sollution of finnish but this is not working or I am not ussing it as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you ever bothered to read what `AsyncTask` has of methods you would have noticed that `AsyncTask` class has a method called `cancel` which accepts `boolean` value.

```
public final boolean cancel (boolean mayInterruptIfRunning);
```

Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason.

read more here [Android Developers AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)